# Externalizing the version of the parent to a variable within POM

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have spring boot project setup which has a parent module and a couple of child modules. One of these child modules is the actual spring boot module and this references the rest of the child modules as jar dependencies. The parent pom is where I manage the dependencies of all my child modules.
The parent pom is where the spring boot starter parent tag is declared. 
In simple projects, I never had to specify the version of the starter dependencies since they were directly being fetched from the starter-parent. But in this project setup the version is not being referenced from the starter parent. I am getting the following error instead:

```
*'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar is missing.*
```

Due to this I am forced to specify the spring-boot version to all my starter-dependencies.

To centralize all these versions I thought of having a single variable in the properties section and then using it for the parent and for the starter dependencies. Something like below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>${boot.version}</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <boot.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</boot.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>${boot.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This does not seem to working. The dependencies are picking up the variable just fine, but the parent is not referencing the variable. Is this something that can be done or is this just an implementation defect ? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import the spring-boot dependencies as a bom instead of as the parent pom. Doing so would place all the dependencies in your dependency management and allowing you to skip the version tag

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Downside: This only works for dependencies and will not work for plugins, so you'll have to add the plugins from the spring-boot-parent by yourself.

Comment: This would required me to remove the parent tag and reintroduce it as a dependency. What I wanted was to keep the parent and refer its version from a variable.. Is that doable ?

Comment: So I guess its not possible. right.? I was given this requirement but wasnt sure if it was possible.

Comment: @KevinPB If you already have several child modules it's a better solution to go via the import part.

Comment: Alright. But in that case, as mentioned by Nicktar, ill have to add the plugins individually into my pom file to get things running. But point taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Different properties are resolvable at different positions. Try to rename `${boot.version}` to `${revision}` (and, of course, `<boot.version>` to `<revision>`).

Comment: Im not sure if this is the issue here. Initially the property name I had given was spring.boot.version. This was not getting picked up even by the dependencies. Once I changed it to boot.version, it was getting picked up.

Comment: You are using Maven 3.5.3 or later?

Comment: 3.5.3 is what im using

Comment: You can probably also set the version in the dependency to `${project.parent.version}`.